# How to break the loop of element by id ().innerText is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I want to apply a condition where, if var `bprodp = document.getElementById('ID_BPMPROD_' + rowIndex).innerText` is undefined or null it should break the while loop and move to next part of code.

I tried if `(bprodp = null)` and `(if bprodp = '')` conditions but it always failed with an error "Unable to get property 'innerText' of undefined or null reference"

Can any one help me, how can i do this.

```
var count = 0;
var rowIndex = 1;
    while (rowIndex <= 4){

    var bprodp = document.getElementById('ID_BPMPROD_' + rowIndex).innerText
    if (bprodp = null){
        break;
    }

    var prodp = document.getElementById('ID_PROD_' + rowIndex).innerText;
    rowIndex++;

    if (bprodp != prodp) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `innerText` is never `null`, it's always a string, it can be the empty string, though. Notice, that you're assigning a value in the `if` condition, not comparing it.

Comment: i tried bprodp = ' ' also , but still it failed

Comment: Because `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison operator.

Comment: You need to use double equals `==` or even triple equals `===` for comparisons in JavaScript. The error message, however, says that the element itself (before getting the `innerText`) is undefined/null (not found).

Comment: Sorry my bad i tried if (bprodp == " ") only

Comment: yes so how can i put that error in condition. so that the code doesn't fails but loop breaks and next part runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking the return value of `document.getElementById()`, not `innerText`. If the element exists, `innerText` will always be a string, never `null`.

```js
while (rowIndex <= 4) {

  var bprodp = document.getElementById('ID_BPMPROD_' + rowIndex);

  if (!bprodp) {
    break;
  }

  var prodp = document.getElementById('ID_PROD_' + rowIndex);
  rowIndex++;

  if (bprodp.innerText != prodp.innerText) {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked....I am new to coding world. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Compare vales not assign:

```
If (bprodp === null){
....
```

Comment: Don't bother posting an answer to this common typo error. It should be noted in a comment and then the question closed.